# Uniform convergence of continuous functions with Lipschitz limit

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity, compactness, uniform-convergence

Let $K \subset \mathbb R^d$ be a compact. Let $\phi_{\varepsilon} \colon K \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be continuous and converge uniformly to $\phi$. Suppose further that $\phi$ is Lipschitz continuous. Can we deduce that $\phi_{\varepsilon}$ are Lipschitz continuous for $\varepsilon$ small?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't get how you could say something about the terms of the sequence from the limit... If you change the first term, you still converge towards the same limit...

Comment: Arzela-Ascoli says that the sequence is bounded and equicontinuous. My question is, since Lipschitz converge to Lipschitz, does the converse apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $d=1$ and $K=[0,1]$ take $\phi _\epsilon =\epsilon \sqrt x$

Then $\phi _ {\epsilon } $ converges uniformly to the constant function $f\equiv 0$
which is a lipschitz function

But no $\phi _ \epsilon $ is lipschitz.